# How to download the html that is open on a page in the browser using Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Is there any way to use the node to check a page that is open in the browser and get its html content?
When I send a get to this page the "data" is not accessible, but when I open it in Chrome, I can see the request's response on the network, so I made a function that opens this page in the browser, and now I would like to get it access the same html content that I see in the inspect, but in my script in node js

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please share your code and read the SO documentation about providing a "minimal, reproducible example", so someone can help you!

Comment: please add the GET request with all of the headers and everything and the response you are getting. Also, compare your GET request to the request that the browser is doing.

Comment: @Oddin Bingo! I copied the entire request header that was shown on the Chrome Network, and used it as a parameter with axios.get (url, {headers: {}}); thankss :D